# Does a wormhole distort the spacetime between its heads?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, wormholes

My friend and I were discussing wormholes, and an issue came up concerning the distortion of spacetime around the heads of the wormhole. In particular, consider the classic wormhole depiction given below:

[image]

In Fig. 1 b) of [Thorne and Misner's review article.](http://www.cmp.caltech.edu/refael/league/thorne-morris.pdf) This picture basically depicts the neck of the wormhole connecting two separate regions of spacetime in our own universe. If such a wormhole were created between points $r_1$ and $r_2$, wouldn't this mean that the spacetime around these points would have to be "pinched" closer to each other (as depicted in the picture) to allow a wormhole to form a shortcut between the points? I think this is just the fault of the oversimplified illustration, but I would greatly appreciate a more correct, technical discussion of how a wormhole could physically connect two spatially distant spacetime points.

EDIT: Clarified the question a little.

Comment: Hi Joshuah, I edited in the picture as a lot of users don't like going offsite and then losing the thread of your argument. Also, if the pdf is removed,  your picture is gone as well. Best of luck with it.

Comment: @CountTo10 I would not mark this as duplicate because the post you've identified as the prior one is way too broad, i.e. it asks too many questions. This post is much better in that it asks *one specific focused* question.

Comment: What do you mean by "extra-dimensional topology of the universe"? As written I don't understand what you're asking. It's also confusing because first you ask if the mouth of the wormhole distorts space-time, which is a perfectly fine question, but then you ask a *different* question when you say that you essentially want a complete general explanation of how wormholes connect to distant spacetime tpoints. Note also that the latter question is pretty vague and broad. Maybe just delete that last part?

Comment: @DanielSank.    Retracted VTC, thanks for the advice for future duplicates

Comment: I agree with DaniekSank that this question is confusing. By definition, a wormhole is a "distortion in spacetime", since non-distorted (i.e. flat) spacetime doesn't have wormholes in it, has it? The "extradimensional" qualifier to "topology" is likewise unclear, but if you omit it, there are indeed theorems that prohibit many kinds of topology changes.